# Angular.js edit in place with password

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

This is my example  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/genxer34/aLRGN/)

I want to add password protect, when i click to "Edit title".

How can i do it?

JS code:

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Welcome to this demo!";
  $scope.editorEnabled = false;

  $scope.enableEditor = function() {
    $scope.editorEnabled = true;
    $scope.editableTitle = $scope.title;
  };

  $scope.disableEditor = function() {
    $scope.editorEnabled = false;
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.title = $scope.editableTitle;
    $scope.disableEditor();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a $scope.checkPassword (or something meaningful) function which shows a popup/modal/etc where the user can input the password and then make an ajax call to verify for the password. If the password entered is correct enable editor else do nothing. Or maybe you want to allow save password if the user authenticates successfully.

UPDATE:

I think password verification should be handled totally by the server. I would make a call to function that handles authentication before saving the password (on the server). So make sure that you send the password as a parameter with the save call.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But can you do some demo?